# Unable to delete database "Waiting for table metadata lock" Error

Tags: mysql, drop-database

I was copying a db from an RDS server, using phpmyadmin copy, to same server, one table contains huge number of records, and after approximately an hour it was still not completed, so i killed the copy process, but now i am unable to delete the database, whenever i try to delete that table or drop target database,query stops responding and when i fetch process list,  "Waiting for table metadata lock" State is always there.

Comment: have you tried dropping it command line?

Comment: I was using command line but no success, problem resolved when i tried to drop after approximately 12 hours, as transaction might have been timeout and locks released.